# Subscribe to events of an existing RichTextContentControl

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, openxml, openoffice-writer

I'm trying to access all Rich-Text-Content-Controls of an existing *.docx* Document (Office Open XML).

I've found a way to get all Content Controls of a Document by looping over a specified range:

```
var contentControls = new List<ContentControl>();
Range rangeStory;
foreach (Range range in wordDocument.StoryRanges)
{
    rangeStory = range;
    do
    {
        try
        {
            contentControls.AddRange(rangeStory.ContentControls.Cast<ContentControl>());
        }
        catch (COMException) { }
        rangeStory = rangeStory.NextStoryRange;
    }
    while (rangeStory != null);
}
```

But I can't find a way to cast these **ContentControl**s (assembly: `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`) to **RichTextContentControl**s (assembly: `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word`).

```
RichTextContentControl richTextContentControl = contentControl as RichTextContentControl;
throws Exception
```

I want to do this casting, because I need to subscribe to RichTextContentControl's **entering** and **exiting** events.

```
richTextContentControl.Entering += (sender, args) => {/*..*/ };
richTextContentControl.Exiting += (sender, args) => {/*..*/ };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! There is a very easy way to access any kind of Content Controls via Vsto:

```
foreach (var result in thisDocument.Controls.OfType<RichTextContentControl>())
{
    result.Entering += (sender, args) =>
    {
        MediatorContext.Current.Send(new CurrentKomponenteChangedRequest(result.ID, State.Entering));
    };

    result.Exiting += (sender, args) =>
    {
        MediatorContext.Current.Send(new CurrentKomponenteChangedRequest(result.ID, State.Exiting));
    };
}
```